# CORS configuration issue with FineUploader Azure

Tags: cors, fine-uploader

I'm using the React version of FineUploader to upload files to Azure blob storage and the uploader is giving me the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I set up the backend with the following code to set CORS settings. This code is a slightly modified version of the code sample from FineUploader here:
https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/C%23/azure/FineUploaderAzureServer.cs

```
public async Task ConfigureCors()
{
   var ALLOWED_CORS_ORIGINS = new List<String> { "http://myapp.com", "http://localhost:3333"};
   var ALLOWED_CORS_HEADERS = new List<String> { "x-ms-meta-qqfilename", "Content-Type", "x-ms-blob-type", "x-ms-blob-content-type" };
   const CorsHttpMethods ALLOWED_CORS_METHODS = CorsHttpMethods.Delete | CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Options;
   const int ALLOWED_CORS_AGE_DAYS = 5;

   var properties = await _client.GetServicePropertiesAsync();

   properties.DefaultServiceVersion = "2013-08-15";
   await _client.SetServicePropertiesAsync(properties);

   var addRule = true;
   if (addRule)
   {
      var ruleWideOpenWriter = new CorsRule()
      {
         AllowedHeaders = ALLOWED_CORS_HEADERS,
         AllowedOrigins = ALLOWED_CORS_ORIGINS,
         AllowedMethods = ALLOWED_CORS_METHODS,
         MaxAgeInSeconds = (int)TimeSpan.FromDays(ALLOWED_CORS_AGE_DAYS).TotalSeconds
      };
   properties.Cors.CorsRules.Clear();
   properties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(ruleWideOpenWriter);
   await _client.SetServicePropertiesAsync(properties);
   }
}
```

The above code is working fine. When I log into my Azure portal, I see these settings under my storage account's CORS tab.

As I was researching, I noticed that someone suggested the issue could be due to request coming from localhost. I moved the app to an Azure website to test it and I'm still getting the same error. I did include the new URL for this test site in my CORS settings.

And here's my fine uploader wrapper initialization:

```
const uploader = new FineUploaderAzure({
    options: {
      cors: {
          expected: true,
          sendCredentials: true
      },
      signature: {
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:49065/getsas'
      },
      request: {
          endpoint: 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/test-container'
      },
      uploadSuccess: {
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:49065/success'
      }
    }
})
```

Any idea what's causing this issue?

UPDATE:
Here's a screen shot of the CORS settings I see on my Azure portal:
[image]

And here's the code that specifies the options:[image]

Here's the screen shot of request header from Chrome:[image]

Comment: Please show the exact request url and headers alone with an exact display of your cors rules per azure

Comment: Added screen shots to original post.

Comment: I'll need the request info, headers, etc according to browser dev tools too

Comment: You can go to http://ingridfileuploader.azurewebsites.net which is an exact copy of the local react app I'm running at http://localhost:3333. The http://localhost:49065 is an exact copy of my API app running locally.

Comment: Just added a screen shot of request header from Chrome. Also if I didn't give all you need, it may be easier for you to just go to http://ingridfileuploader.azurewebsites.net and try to upload a file.

Comment: Your hosted project doesn't work at all. It's trying to send a SAS request to localhost.

Comment: Yes, I do receive it on my localhost but it won't work for you. Did I give you all the information you needed?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, so i'm not sure what you would like me to do next.

Comment: I'm updating the apps -- both frontend and backend so that it will send a request to my actual API app. Please give me a minute. I'll let you know when they're updated.

Comment: I updated both, please give it a try again at http://ingridfileuploader.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your SAS endpoint (https://ingridapp.azurewebsites.net), not with Azure Blob Storage. You haven't setup your SAS endpoint to handle CORS/cross-origin requests.

Comment: Oh! I wasn't aware of that. I must have missed it. I was following this document here: https://docs.fineuploader.com/endpoint_handlers/azure.html. Could you please point me to where I can find info on handling CORS request in my SAS endpoint?

Comment: There's no possible way for me to document that or provide any advice. If you choose to setup your SAS server on a domain other than the one serving your app (which you have done) you'll need to research setting up CORS for requests from Fine Uploader Azure. That will be server and language specific.

Comment: OK. I see what you mean now. They actually won't be two separate apps. As I was getting familiar with FineUploader, I separated them. The idea is to  have FineUploader a part of my main app. Thank you for your help.

Comment: BTW, I read the story of FineUploader on your blog. Your dedication to supporting the developers using FineUploader is truly admirable and commendable. Your help is truly appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. I try, but it is overwhelming at times, which is why my answers are generally terse. My apologies for that. BTW - best reference for CORS is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: You've been very helpful so no worries and thank you for the link. How can we help you? Maybe a step-by-step video? Once I get it up and running and learn enough about FineUploader, I can make a video if you think it would be helpful to you and the community.